# Filter keys out of response

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have an xslt sheet in which I have 2 response objects. $response1 contains a list of ids something like:

```
<response>
  <idlist>
    <id>1</id>
    <id>2</id>
  </idlist>
</response>
```

And $response2 contains a number of objects:

```
<response2>
  <obj id="1" name="obj1"/>
  <obj id="2" name="obj2"/>
  <obj id="3" name="obj3"/>
  <obj id="4" name="obj4"/>
</response2>
```

I want to make a copy of response2 but filtering out any objects where the id matches thos contained in response 1

```
<xsl:variable name="copy">
  <xsl:copy-of select="$response2/*[not contains($response1, id)]"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

any ideas greatly appreciated
C

Answer (score 0):

Given a **well-formed** input such as:

```
<root>
  <response>
    <idlist>
      <id>1</id>
      <id>2</id>
    </idlist>
  </response>
  <response2>
    <obj id="1" name="obj1"/>
    <obj id="2" name="obj2"/>
    <obj id="3" name="obj3"/>
    <obj id="4" name="obj4"/>
  </response2>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="ids" select="response/idlist/id" />
    <output>
        <xsl:copy-of select="response2/obj[not(@id=$ids)]"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <obj id="3" name="obj3"/>
   <obj id="4" name="obj4"/>
</output>
```

---

A better solution is to use a **[key](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)** to link the nodes by matching `id`:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="id" match="id" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:copy-of select="response2/obj[not(key('id', @id))]"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```